# Trouble setting up the loops. (C++)

Tags: c++

Your program will write to the specified output file all the data that appear in the specified input file but that do not appear in the standard input stream.

I've scanned all the values from input file to the fileInput array.
and also all the command line streams to the array stdInput.

```
fileInput [i]; 
stdInput [j];
```

//now i just want to print the values that are present in fileInput but not present in the stdInput

```
for (i = 0; i <= (totalNumbersInfile); i++) 
      for (j = 0; j <= argc; j++)
```

// Here I'm having trouble how do i write if... else here if i just write

```
      if (fileInput[i] == stdInput[j])
         continue;
      else
          cout << fileInput[i] << endl;
```

// this little if ... else prints all the values from fileInput till it gets to the "=="

Comment: It's a little unclear what your question is to me.

Comment: The command line is not the same as `stdin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array is a bad choice for your problem as it will take N*M comparisons(N in stdInput,M in fileInput). Better put in unordered map, then you can do

```
for (int i: fileInput)
     if i not in stdInput
        print i
```